# Non-ASCII characters in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, unicode, characters, biber, greek

I am using `biblatex` with `backend=biber` and the following `.bib` file:

```
@article{concellon_synthesis_2006,
    title = {Synthesis of Enantiopure ({αS,βS)-} or ({αR,βS)-β-Amino} Alcohols by Complete Regioselective Opening of Aminoepoxides by Organolithium Reagents {LiAlH4} or {LiAlD4}},
    volume = {71},
    number = {17},
    journal = {J. Org. Chem.},
    author = {Concellón, José M. and Bernad, Pablo L. and del Solar, Virginia and Suárez, José Ramón and García-Granda, Santiago and Díaz, M. Rosario},
    month = aug,
    year = {2006},
    pages = {6420--6426},
}
```

I can successfully compile this with `biber`, but then the `pdflatex` command fails due to the `α` and `β` in the `.bbl` file.
I am astonished by the fact that there seems to be no elegant solution for this problem even though this appears to be an everyday scenario, in scientific literature at least.

What options do I have to fix this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to assign a meaning to the Unicode characters you're using and that aren't set by default. Here's a way.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{concellon_synthesis_2006,
    title = {Synthesis of Enantiopure ({αS,βS)-} or ({αR,βS)-β-Amino} Alcohols by Complete Regioselective Opening of Aminoepoxides by Organolithium Reagents {LiAlH4} or {LiAlD4}},
    volume = {71},
    number = {17},
    journal = {J. Org. Chem.},
    author = {Concellón, José M. and Bernad, Pablo L. and del Solar, Virginia and Suárez, José Ramón and García-Granda, Santiago and Díaz, M. Rosario},
    month = aug,
    year = {2006},
    pages = {6420--6426},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{α}{\ensuremath{\alpha}}
\newunicodechar{β}{\ensuremath{\beta}}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{concellon_synthesis_2006}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The usage of `filecontents` is just for getting a self-contained MWE.

---

A different solution is to use the `\textgreek` package, which also spares from `newunicodechar` because it defines the meaning of the Unicode Greek letters to be equivalent to their `\text...` counterpart. So `α` becomes `\textalpha`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{concellon_synthesis_2006,
    title = {Synthesis of Enantiopure ({αS,βS)-} or ({αR,βS)-β-Amino} Alcohols by Complete Regioselective Opening of Aminoepoxides by Organolithium Reagents {LiAlH4} or {LiAlD4}},
    volume = {71},
    number = {17},
    journal = {J. Org. Chem.},
    author = {Concellón, José M. and Bernad, Pablo L. and del Solar, Virginia and Suárez, José Ramón and García-Granda, Santiago and Díaz, M. Rosario},
    month = aug,
    year = {2006},
    pages = {6420--6426},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{textgreek}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{concellon_synthesis_2006}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: I get the following error when running `pdflatex`, `biber` and `pdflatex` on your file:
`! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:α not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Comment: The second solution should be preferred as far as IUPAC is concerned: they recommend to use upright greek letters (and of course `\ce{LiALH4}` with `mhchem`, but that's another topic...)

Answer (score 10):

biber is designed to be able to recode into TeX macros automatically in exactly this situation. This is explained in the biber manual - the problem you face is a limitation of `inputenc` and PDFLaTeX which doesn't understand all of UTF-8. Load biblatex with the `safeinputenc` option and then call biber with the `--output_safecharsset=full` option. This will do it all automatically for you.

To switch to the textgreek variants, it's quite easy, you have to have a custom UTF-8<->TeX macro XML conversion data file (biber comes with a default which is fine for most use). To use the textgreek variants, get this file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ln3ht1xd9mmgu9w/recode.xml

Then call biber like this:

```
biber --recodedata=<path to file downloaded above>
```

Then just make sure you have `\usepackage{textgreek}` in your LaTeX document and you are using the `safeinputenc` option to biblatex.

A much easier way of dealing with this is just switching to LuaLaTeX since biber deals with UTF-8 without problems. Then there is no need for special biber option or the `safeintputenc` biblatex option.

Comment: Thank you for this very elegant solution, however, @cgnieder mentioned the IUPAC and with your solution the α is an `$\alpha$` and not a `\textalpha` in the `.bbl` file. Do you have solution for that?

Comment: Updated answer for using textgreek variants.

Answer (score 3):

If using Unicode is what you want, you should consider using [fontspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) together with a Unicode font with Greek letters (which virtually all Unicode fonts have). Here I have used Linux Libertine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,fontspec,biblatex}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{concellon_synthesis_2006,
    title = {Synthesis of Enantiopure ({αS,βS)-} or ({αR,βS)-β-Amino} Alcohols by Complete Regioselective Opening of Aminoepoxides by Organolithium Reagents {LiAlH4} or {LiAlD4}},
    volume = {71},
    number = {17},
    journal = {J. Org. Chem.},
    author = {Concellón, José M. and Bernad, Pablo L. and del Solar, Virginia and Suárez, José Ramón and García-Granda, Santiago and Díaz, M. Rosario},
    month = aug,
    year = {2006},
    pages = {6420--6426}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{concellon_synthesis_2006}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to PLK and cgnieder I managed to find a solution that I am happy with. It is based on PLK's answer but also ensures that the Greek letters are upright.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{concellon_synthesis_2006,
    title = {Synthesis of Enantiopure ({αS,βS)-} or ({αR,βS)-β-Amino} Alcohols by Complete Regioselective Opening of Aminoepoxides by Organolithium Reagents {LiAlH4} or {LiAlD4}},
    volume = {71},
    number = {17},
    journal = {J. Org. Chem.},
    author = {Concellón, José M. and Bernad, Pablo L. and del Solar, Virginia and Suárez, José Ramón and García-Granda, Santiago and Díaz, M. Rosario},
    month = aug,
    year = {2006},
    pages = {6420--6426},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\usepackage[backend=biber, safeinputenc]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{concellon_synthesis_2006}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now, the macro file (found on [Biber CTAN](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/biblio/biber/biblatex-biber.tar.gz) `/biblatex-biber-1.5/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml`) has to be edited. This:

```xml
<maps type="greek" set="full">
    <map><from>alpha</from>      <to hex="3B1">α</to></map>
    <map><from>beta</from>       <to hex="3B2">β</to></map>
    ...
    <map><from>Omega</from>      <to hex="3A9">Ω</to></map>
  </maps>
```

Has to be changed to this:

```xml
  <maps type="wordmacros" set="base,full">
    <map><from>textalpha</from>      <to hex="3B1">α</to></map>
    <map><from>textbeta</from>       <to hex="3B2">β</to></map>
    ...
    <map><from>textOmega</from>      <to hex="3A9">Ω</to></map>
  </maps>
```

and saved in your working directory. The package `textgreek` provides the `\textalpha` command which results in an upright `α`.

Run `Biber` with the following options:

```
--recodedata=recode_data.xml
```

And the following `pdflatex` run should produce a bibliography with upright Greek letters.

Comment: If you want to follow IUPAC to the letter: they recommend to set Cahn-Ingold-Prelog descriptors like _S_ and _R_ with an italic font series

Comment: If you are making a custom recode XML (as you are), you can decide which recode "set" the mappings go into so you can set `set="base,full"` and then you don't need the `--output_safecharsset=full` option since "base" is the default for biber.